# row deleting event giving error in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

While deleting a row from a gridview an error with this message is thrown:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

aspx code

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridviewEditProformaInvoice" OnRowEditing="gridviewEditProformaInvoice_RowEditing" AutoGenerateEditButton="true"  OnRowCancelingEdit="gridviewEditProformaInvoice_RowCancelingEdit" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" OnRowUpdating="gridviewEditProformaInvoice_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="gridviewEditProformaInvoice_RowDeleting" ></asp:GridView>
```

code behind

```
protected void gridviewEditProformaInvoice_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["abc"].ConnectionString);
     GridViewRow row = gridviewEditProformaInvoice.Rows[e.RowIndex];
           
     string uniqueid = (row.Cells[2].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"delete from tbl_proformaDetails WHERE uniqueid ='" + uniqueid + "'", abc);
}
```

Comment: On which line you get this error?

Comment: string uniqueid = (row.Cells[2].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;//error

Comment: @krishnamohan - Why don't you use `FindControl` method instead if you know that it is a _textbox_? to avoid these kind of obvious exceptions raised with index?

Comment: but its auto generate columns true.

Comment: @krishnamohan - Then why you are _typecasting_ it to a textbox control? Simply use `row.cells[2].Text` if your `uniqueid` is in the third column.